# How can I display and edit decimal values in SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, nsdecimalnumber

I am working on a SwiftUI project and I need to allow users to enter decimal values in a TextField. However, the default behavior of SwiftUI's TextField seems to only support integer values. I would like to know how I can modify the TextField to accept and display decimal values.

I have tried using the formatter: numberFormatter() property and keyboardType(.decimalPad) modifier on the TextField, but it doesn't seem to affect the behaviour. The TextField still only allows me to enter whole numbers.

Here is the code example. The list of items are look like below. I want to display and edit the price property of the object.

```
 @State private var items: [Item] = [
        Item(name: "Item 1", quantity: 10, price: 10.5),
        Item(name: "Item 2", quantity: 5, price: 12.5),
        Item(name: "Item 3", quantity: 3, price: 16000.3)
    ]

...
```

And the textfields are look like below,

```
...


HStack {
                    TextField("Item Description", text: $items[index].name)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    TextField("Quantity", value: $items[index].quantity, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    TextField("Price", value: $items[index].price, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    
                }
```

Comment: have you tried using your own `NumberFormatter` in the `TextField`, such as `let formatter = NumberFormatter()` with 
            `formatter.numberStyle = .decimal`

Comment: @loremipsum The link you provided does not resolve my problem. Because there is no parameter called "format" in the TextField() method. There is a "Formatter" parameter. In the formatter field I can pass a NumberFormatter() ( based on workingdog support Ukraine's answer). By the way thank you for your kind suggestion.

Comment: There is, unless you are supporting iOS 13 or 14

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't init objects inline like: `formatter: NumberFormatter()` it's a memory leak, either use a static object or use the new convenience `format: .currency`. Also `ForEach` is not a for loop, you shouldn't have `$items[index].name` because it'll crash. Instead use `ForEach($items) { $item in` and then use `text: $item.name` and `Item` should be `Identifiable`.